# cakephp login not working properly.

Tags: cakephp, authentication, module

This is ctp file location on my server localhost/cakephp/view/login/index.ctp

```
   <div class="wrapper">
        <form class="form1" action="posts">
        <div class="formtitle">Login to your account</div>
        <div class="input">
            <div class="inputtext">Username: </div>
            <div class="inputcontent">
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input nobottomborder">
            <div class="inputtext">Password: </div>
            <div class="inputcontent">
                <input type="password" />
                <br/><a href="#">Forgot password?</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <input class="greybutton" type="submit" value="Cancel" />
            <input class="orangebutton" type="submit" value="Login" />
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>
```

for user controller

```
class LoginController extends AppController {

var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

public function index() {

}
function login() {
    // if the form was submitted
    if(!empty($this->data)) {
        // find the user in the database
        $dbuser = $this->User->findByUsername($this->data['User']['username']);
        // if found and passwords match
        if(!empty($dbuser) && ($dbuser['User']['password'] == md5($this->data['User']['password']))) {
            // write the username to a session
            $this->Session->write('User', $dbuser);
            // save the login time
            $dbuser['User']['last_login'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $this->User->save($dbuser);
            // redirect the user
            $this->Session->setFlash('You have successfully logged in.');
            $this->redirect('/posts/');
        } else {
            $this->set('error', 'Either your username or password is incorrect.');
        }
    }
}

function logout() {
    // delete the user session
    $this->Session->delete('User');
    // redirect to posts index page
    $this->Session->setFlash('You have successfully logged out.');
    $this->redirect('/posts/');
}

}
```

I am not using default theme but custom theme its location on view/themed/default. It's working.
Now I can't login auth so please let me solution of it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: why aren't you using the Form Helper in your views? That'll automagically insert the right values, if you configure them properly.

Second: your form points to 'posts', while you want to point to 'Users/login'.

At last: your input fields don't have any name specified. That way the controller will never know what to do with it, IF the form was pointing to the right controller.

I suggest you read the books tutorial 'Simple Authorization'. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

P.S. You didn't specify the CakePHP version. I'm asuming that it is 2.X...